# Is there a function whose nth derivative is always 1?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Just like the question says, is there ANY function whatsoever, that when taking the nth order derivative will equal one or any constant for that matter (that is not 0)?

For clarification, does a function $f(x)$ exist such that $f^{(n)}(x) = 1$ for every $n$

Comment: If the $n$-th derivative of function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a constant $c$, then its $(n+1)$-th derivative is $0$. So it is not possible to find a function whose $n$-th derivative is always equal to $1$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio The question is ambiguous. Joe thinks it wants a function that works for every $n$; you think it asks for a function for a specific $n$. The question itself doesn't really say.

Comment: @DavidK It would have been nice if the answerers would have waited until this crucial detail is clarified. But they prefered to guess and answer.

Comment: Edited the question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: The question also mentions "or any constant for that matter", and $0$ can be such constant for that matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{(n)}(x) = 1$ for every $n$, there is no such function. This is because, if $f'(x) = 1$, then $f''(x) = 0$, since the derivative of a constant function is $0$.

However, there is a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and a *specific number* $x_0$ such that $f^{(n)}(x_0) = 1$ for all $n$. (Take $f(x) = e^x$ and $x_0 = 0$, for example.)

Comment: Ah yea, I didn't think about that. Thank you very much